I am trying to downgrade php 8 to php 7 using brew
diptonarh@Diptos-MacBook-Air ~ % brew unlink php
Error: No such keg: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php
diptonarh@Diptos-MacBook-Air ~ % 

How can i solve the error
Error: No such keg: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php

note: I am trying to use brew for downgrade.

Please keep in mind that PHP 7 should not be used any where. Also, if brew unlink php throws an error, are you sure this is directly related to PHP?

You should specify the php version you are about to unlink.
For example:
brew unlink php@8.2

If you do have PHP 8 installed it might not have been via brew. As you did not say which operating system you are using it's impossible for us to know how it was originally installed.
You can check if PHP is installed using the command
brew services

which lists them all. You should see and line starting php and the status of the service.
However, PHP 7 is now obsolete so you will not be able to install it directly using brew, it will give you an error message.
You can install PHP 7 on a Mac using the brew tap shivammathur/php which you install first
brew tap shivammathur/php

followed by the command to install PHP
brew install shivammathur/php/php@7.4

then set up your path
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/php@7.4/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/php@7.4/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

